# [Navigation stack] A question about move_base

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As stated [here](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base), the move_base package is going to compute the velocity to publish on /cmd_vel in order to drive the robot to reach the goal (if present).
In the tutorial about Navigation stack there an example on "[How to publish Odometry Transform](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom)".
But looking at the file the author is going to define some variables for velocity and position:

```
  12   double x = 0.0;
  13   double y = 0.0;
  14   double th = 0.0;
  15 
  16   double vx = 0.1;
  17   double vy = -0.1;
  18   double vth = 0.1;
```

integrating them later in a loop:

```
  30     //compute odometry in a typical way given the velocities of the robot
  31     double dt = (current_time - last_time).toSec();
  32     double delta_x = (vx * cos(th) - vy * sin(th)) * dt;
  33     double delta_y = (vx * sin(th) + vy * cos(th)) * dt;
  34     double delta_th = vth * dt;
  35 
  36     x += delta_x;
  37     y += delta_y;
  38     th += delta_th;
```

Now, my question is:

- are those variable necessary in the file just to give the reader an idea on how to move the robot using odometry? And they **MUST** be removed when the robot is receiving data over `/cmd_vel` form the move_base?
  Since they are integrating above time in the loop they are going to put wrong cmd_vel information to the robot (in my opinion). Or are they necessary in any case?
- What about if the robot is going to be simulated? Since I dn t have any odometry source I should create some data. Are in this case those variables necessary?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191597/%5Bnavigation-stack%5D-a-question-about-move_base/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-08-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes; the vx, vy and vth values in the tutorial are samples, and should be replaced with real encoder data when using a real robot.

Note that the tutorial you linked to is publishing odometry messages, not cmd_vel, and that odometry represents the position feedback from the wheel sensors, not a command to move the robot.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-09-01**:
Hendrix: if you look at line 69 to 72 it is going to publish velocity as well.
odom.**twist**.**twist**.linear....

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-01**:
No. Those lines are setting the velocity estimate within the Odometry message. It's still part of the Odometry message and published on the `odom` topic, not `cmd_vel`

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-09-01**:
Ok, but you said: *not a command to move the robot.*
Reading the tutorial one gets the impression that odometry information is used to updated the new position of the robot, then braodcasted over ROS and then move_base use that informations to calculate /cmd_vel.  Many times uses the word "velocity"

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-01**:
The Odometry represents the *current state of the robot*: position and speed. move_base calculates a new  velocity command based on the current speed, position, acceleration limits, obstacles and goal of the robot.